# Remove space from MYSQL table field

Tags: php, mysql

HI I have a databse with 1.6 million UK postcodes, with latitudes and longtitude.  The problem is half of the entries as formed as one string like this SS164LT  and the other half is formed like this, SS16 4LT, which makes looking up a postcode a bit of a nightmare, is there a way to remove the space so they are all formatted as one string no spaces.

I have tried the code below, but it doesn't remove the space.

```
 $result1 = mysql_query("update postcodes set postcode= REPLACE(postcode,'      ',' ')") 
 or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: You're almost there `REPLACE(postcode,' ','')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql_query("update postcodes set postcode= REPLACE(postcode,' ','')");
```

I would run it in phpMyAdmin though instead of from your own code - easier to test and finetune.